# How can import sql database file in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am trying to import sql database file into mysql in ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
While i run this command in terminal.

```
mysql -u root -p myNewdb < mydb.sql
```

It throws me an error saying.

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: It looks like an error from within the sql file.  Is there a particular line perhaps where the problem is occurring?

Comment: I check my file and its not the problem of my sql file at all.

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the password:  mysql -uusername -p'(password)' name-of-db < /file/to/the/db.sql

Answer (score 0):

**Import Singal database**

mysql -u root -p database_name < /database path)[enter link description here](http://solveubuntu.blogspot.in/p/server.html)